# Can I get a question I asked with a temp account linked to my real account?

Tags: support

I asked [Is it possible to enable System Protection from the command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/861170/is-it-possible-to-enable-system-protection-from-the-command-prompt) while my computer was in an Automatic Repair cycle of *Doom*.

I used a temp account to ask it. Is it possible to get it linked to my real account? Otherwise the question will perpetually show up as not having an accepted answer even though I figured out how to solve my problem.

Comment: Use the contact us link to request a account merger

Comment: @JourneymanGeek well that was easier than I expected.